# Injecting in AuthenticatorService, SyncAdapter and Application with Dagger

Tags: android, dagger

At the moment I am working on an Android application which uses ContentProviders, SyncAdapter and AuthenticatorService as base for syncing the apps data with a REST Api. I want to inject modules with Dagger into the application and the services. I made a application class like this:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private ObjectGraph objectGraph;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(
               new DataModule()
        );
    }

    public ObjectGraph getObjectGraph() {
        return this.objectGraph;
    }
}
```

In my AuthenticatorActivity I want to inject the dependencies. I used the following code:

```
((App) getApplication()).getObjectGraph().inject(this)
```

I'm getting an error which says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.App
```

The AuthenticatorActivity is opened by my AuthenticatorService which I built into the app with the instructions from here http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-authenticator.html

Is it possible to inject dependencies into services anyway with Dagger? Or do I need to use other code to access the ObjectGraph?

Comment: Did you specify in your `AndroidManifest` that `App` should be used as the `Application` instance?

Comment: That did the trick, absolutely forgot to set the android:name attribute. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I'm vote closing the question as 'non-reproducible'.

Comment: That should rather be an answer, shouldn't it?